# how to pass data from one window to another in titanium (classic)?

Tags: javascript, titanium

'MyHTTPlink (mentioned in my code] consists some Restaurant Name, url, address. Using this code to i list all restaurant name and url in my table. Now I want to do, how to send the table row details to next window(.js page). The restaurant url consist lot of menu items for each restaurant. List the menu items in table row on next page. How to code that?'

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow ({  backgorundColor: '#000'}); 

var tableview = Ti.UI.createTableView({ 
 height:'auto', 
 layout:'vertical', 
 top:5, 
 right:5, 
 bottom:5, left:5 });

var data = [];

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient ({
onload: function () {

    alert("success!");
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.connectionResponses.length; i++) {


        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height: 60,
        });

        var restLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text: json.connectionResponses[i].restaurantName, 
            height: 'auto',
            left:54,
            top: 5,
            font:{ fontSize:20 } 
        });
        var connLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text: json.connectionResponses[i].connectingurl, 
            height: 'auto',
            left:54,
            bottom:5,
            font:{ fontSize:14 } 

        });
        var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
            image:'images/menu_icon.png',  
            top:4, 
            left:0, 
            height:45, 
            width:41 
        });

        row.add(restLabel);
        row.add(connLabel);
        row.add(image);
        data.push(row);
    }

    tableview.setData(data);

   },
   onerror: function () {
        alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
   }
   //timeout:5000
   });

xhr.open("GET", "http:MYHTTPlink"); 
xhr.send();

tableview.addEventListener('click',function(e){
     //alert("RS Name : " +e.row.title);
     var winn = Ti.UI.createWindow({ url:'hotelpage.js'});
     winn.open();
    //var hostelwin = require('hotelpage').gethotelWin;
    //var newwin = new hotelwin();
    //newwin.open();
  });

   win.add(tableview);

   win.open();
```

Comment: I suggest you use Modules (require) due to you can pass values at constructor. For example: var hostelwin = require('hotelpage')(e.row.title, data[e]); where e.row.title is the title of tableViewCell and data[e] a hashMap with data of each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please just check below Code and use in your code. 
you can perform your work like this.

```
tableview.addEventListener('click',function(e){
         //alert("RS Name : " +e.row.title);
         var winn = Ti.UI.createWindow({ 
             url:'hotelpage.js',
             row_title : e.row.title,
             all_info: e.row,
         });
         winn.open();
        //var hostelwin = require('hotelpage').gethotelWin;
        //var newwin = new hotelwin();
        //newwin.open();
      });
```

**and in "hotelpage.js"**

```
var curtWind = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
// Get Data like this 
var title = curtWind.row_title;
var allData = curtWind.all_info;
// and you can use as per your requirement.
```

May be this is Helpful for you,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what MRT answered that is correct and working, you could use this code that avoid the use of url property as recommended here: [Titanium 3.X documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-url)

**In your code:**

```
tableview.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    hotelWin = require('/yourpath/hotelpage');
    var hotelW = new hotelWin(e.row.title, e.row.id)
  });
```

**In hotelpage.js**

```
function external(title, id) {
    var hotelPageWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    //properties here
    });

    //You have available here two variables: 
    //title with assigned the value of e.row.title
    //id with assigned the value of e.row.id

    hotelPageWin.open();

    return hotelPageWin;
};

module.exports = external;
```

Comment: how to use the e.row.title and id on next page

Comment: You have the values in two variables. I updated the comment in the code.

Comment: @maxdangelo code is also working N good way. But, Satheesh using that type code that's why, I suggest CreateWindow and currentWindow method. And That is also good and working. Depend on you what you Like and perform your tasks.... :)